# Cannot retrieve json from custom js response

Tags: javascript, json, response

I have a custom client object that wraps up the API calls for my single page application using `fetch`, and in tests I want to mock the returned response for each use case.

I'm creating the mocked response this way

```js
// const data = {};
// const status = 200,
const blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(data)], {type : 'application/json'});
const init = { status };
const response = new Response(blob, init);
```

The problem arises when my client try to get response data whith `await response.json()`, this throw an error with message

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
```

Logging the entire response show this

```js
Response {
  [Symbol(realm)]: { settingsObject: {} },
  [Symbol(state)]: {
    aborted: false,
    rangeRequested: false,
    timingAllowPassed: false,
    requestIncludesCredentials: false,
    type: 'default',
    status: 200,
    timingInfo: null,
    cacheState: '',
    statusText: '',
    headersList: HeadersList {
      [Symbol(headers map)]: [Map],
      [Symbol(headers map sorted)]: null
    },
    urlList: [],
    body: { stream: undefined, source: '[object Blob]', length: 13 }
  },
  [Symbol(headers)]: HeadersList {
    [Symbol(headers map)]: Map(1) { 'content-type' => [Object] },
    [Symbol(headers map sorted)]: null
  }
}
```

I think the problem resides in the `body.source` attribute being a `string` with value `'[object Blob]'`, thus not being a valid stringified json.

**Am I building the mocked response correctlly? Do I need to do other stuffs to make it works?**

Comment: "Logging the entire response show this" - what **exactly** did you log? That whole snippet, starting from `Response`, does not look like valid JSON after all

Comment: @NicoHaase I did `console.warn(response)`

Comment: What happens if you use `response.blob()` instead of `response.json()`? Does it return the correct Blob object?

Comment: Logging it as before output `Blob { size: 13, type: 'text/plain;charset=utf-8' }`, but I'd prefer not to switch my client logic from `json()` to `blob()`

Comment: in which environment are you working on? After few tests, your code seems to work in all browsers, but your log shows a different structure from the one i expect to see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response?retiredLocale=it

Am i missing something?

Comment: I'm testing with vitest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, messing and trying around with the code lead finally to something that seems working correctly with my client business logic and code:

```
const jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
const init = {
    status: statusCode,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Content-Length': jsonData.length.toString()
    }
};
const response = Response(jsonData, init);
```

Had to be honest, find this solution asking ChatGPT, so I'm not sure why this version works while the question one doesn't, so if anyone has any clue please tell me.